# how to send error message to slack in new relic

Tags: alert, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am new to new relic and I want to send every error for my application to go to slack. For this I have created Alert condition, Alert Policy and Workflow(connected with slack) but the notification aren't going. I am guessing that there might be a problem with alert policy and alert condition.

This is the query which I am trying to run
[image]

This is the threshold for alert condition, please check

[image]

Comment: First, you need to clarify the problem, what is happening? (a) the alert is activated occasionally but no notification is sent (b) the alert is never activated.

Answer (score 1):

I think a big question is - are the alerts not firing or are notifications not being sent to slack (This would determine whether it's the alert policy/condition causing the issue or whether it's the workflow)?  If you go to your "Issues" page and search for incidents in the last week (Remove the "status = Active" filter), do you see this incident?

I think there are some modifications that also should adjust to get every error:

- Adjust the actual threshold - they currently have their threshold set to `above or equal to 0`, I think they want to change this to  just `above 0`.  One of my thoughts here too would be that our system identifies changes in state according to the threshold, but with `above or equal to 0`, the alert would always be in the failed state and thus would never alarm.
- The next item you could look at would be to change the `for at least 1 minute` to `at least once in 1 minute`.
- The lost signal alert config also doesn't make sense as it would just consider the signal lost after 1 minute (which is when they specified the incident to start) and would immediately close the open incident.